# mac app requires newer version of sqlite but uses the old one

Tags: macos, qt, sqlite, linker

Trying to run / debug an app on mac (Mavericks), that has to use sqlite 3.8.6.

I have the .h and .c files in the project. I have the dylib added as a build resource

```
LIBS += sqlite3/libsqlite3.0.dylib
```

But I also must place the dylib somewhere and tell the program at run-time to use this version.

There is a SQLite version 3.7.13 installed on the system (in `/usr/lib`). It seems to be used preferentially. If I had admin rights (which I don't) I could move it to a different location... But the user system may have it in the default location so that would be useless.

I have tried to place MY sqlite3 in a place that will be used preferentially - like in `myapp.app/Contents/Frameworks` or `myapp.app/Contents/MacOs`... also tried to change the dependency with `install_name_tool`... no success.

Checking the dependencies with `otool -L` shows a dependency on `sqlite3.0.dylib` in `/usr/local/lib` (which does not contain any `sqlite3`)... even after running `install_name_tool` it still shows the same. Perhaps I am doing it wrong...

```
install_name_tool -id @executable_path/Frameworks/libsqlite3.0.dylib myapp.app/Contents/Frameworks/libsqlite3.0.dylib
install_name_tool -change myapp.app/Contents/Frameworks/libsqlite3.0.dylib @executable_path/Frameworks/libsqlite3.0.dylib  myapp.app/Contents/Frameworks/mylib.dylib
install_name_tool -change myapp.app/Contents/Frameworks/libsqlite3.0.dylib @executable_path/Frameworks/libsqlite3.0.dylib  myapp.app/Contents/MacOs/myapp
```

I am getting an SQL error that is caused by having the wrong (older) version of sqlite3, which does not support certain required features.

How can I force the app to see the version I added ?

**Update**: I added the c file and removed the dylib as a dependency...

I got the error `no such module: fts4`

I added the following in the .c file (from http://www.sqlite.org/fts3.html) - as suggested in comments below

```
#define SQLITE_ENABLE_FTS4
#define SQLITE_ENABLE_FTS4_PARENTHESIS
```

Adding the same in windows and linux, the effect is double the size of the library + sqlite3. And queries on a database run significantly slower (I actually thought they were not even performed).

If this is the only option I have on mac, I will have to use it... I am either stuck with very slow build, very large libs, and VERY SLOW QUERIES, or ... there must still be an option to use the `sqlite3.dylib` without building it into the lib I am creating.

Comment: I think you can just add the original (Amalgamation) files `sqlite3.c` and `sqlite3.h` (look for version 3.8.6) to your Xcode project. That's basically it.

Comment: I have the two files in the project. If I do not also include the dylib with he same version, I actually get a build error. But building and choosing the right run-time version are different things... in linux all I had to do was set the LD_LIBRARY_PATH to point at the folder where I had my sqlite3.so file. But on mac, the same thing doesn't seem to work...

Comment: Why not test this with a new Xcode-Project. Create it and add the 2 sqlite3-files to it and add some test code to see the version of the used sqlite3.

Comment: When adding the .c file I get the error "no such module: fts4"

Comment: Read this: http://www.sqlite.org/compile.html

Comment: You should add this line to sqlite3.c: #define SQLITE_ENABLE_FTS4

Comment: Adding the #define in the .c file worked, thank you so much ! Can you please add this as answer so I can accept ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just add the original (`Amalgamation`) files `sqlite3.c` and `sqlite3.h` (look for version 3.8.6) to your Xcode project. That's basically it.

If you need to change/add some compile options 
you can do that at the top in sqlite3.c.

Here an example to activate FTS3/FTS4:

```
#define SQLITE_ENABLE_FTS4
```

All the compile options are here:  http://www.sqlite.org/compile.html

Comment: Thank you for your help, I am accepting this since it works, though if at some point I find a way to use a dylib, instead of building sqlite3 into my lib, it will be better

Comment: Thank You and Good luck! The documentation in Xcode about dynamic libraries is a bit to much for me right now :)